# What can I do with small change from countries I am unlikely to return to?

Tags: money, exchange

I often have small change leftover after visiting a country, usually much less than $1 equivalent.

Keeping it around is a hassle, especially if I'm unlikely to return to that country: I would have to sort it, remember where I put it, remember to look before I travel, etc... In my view this is far too much effort for the few cents I can potentially save in a jar somewhere.

What else can I do with this change?

Comment: Donate it to UNICEF.

Comment: Keep the change as a memento. Give it to your children or grandchildren, old coins from faraway places are usually pretty interesting to kids.

Comment: Give it to your airline to pass on to a charity, eg [British Airway's Flying Start program with Comic Relief](http://www.ba-flyingstart.com/about)?